# fetch and display data using html form into asp page

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, asp-classic

I have two pages (form.html & default.asp). In the HTML page i have the following form:

```
<form method="POST" action="default.asp" name="form1">
<td width="10">
<select name="Practice_ID" size="1" ID="Prac">
     <option value="0" <% if Prac_ID ="0" then%>All</option>
     <option value="1" <% if Prac_ID ="1" then%>HCL</option>
     <option value="2" <% if Prac_ID ="2" then%>Silverbeck</option>
     <option value="3" <% if Prac_ID ="3" then%>TPF</option>
 <option value="4" <% if Prac_ID ="4" then%>Express</option>
</select>
</td>

<p> Client Surname </p>
<input type="text" name="clientsurname" value="" />
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr> 
</form>
```

And in the ASP page i have:

```
<%
dim prac_id
prac_id=Request.Form("form1")

If request("prac_id")<>"" then
Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.open "claims","USERNAME","PASSWORD"
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
rs.Open "SELECT Date_Passed, Agent_ID, Client_First_Name, Client_Surname, Main_Number, Claims_Status FROM Claim_Status WHERE Practice_ID = '"&prac_id&"'", conn

%>

<table border="1">

<tr><th>Date</th><th>Agent</th><th>Client First Name</th><th>Client Surname</th>   <th>Client Number</th><th>Claim Status</th></tr>
<%do until rs.EOF%>
<tr>
<%for each x in rs.Fields%>
<td>
<%Response.Write(x.value)%>
</td>
<%next%>
</tr>
<%
rs.MoveNext
loop
%>
</table>
<%
rs.close
conn.close
End If
%>
```

What I'm trying to do is have a user select an option from the drop down menu and type a surname and return the results on the ASP page (i haven't started with the surname look up yet, still trying to pull results using the drop down menu), currently when I select a practice and hit submit it gives me a blank page (no errors)
It is pulling data from SQL server (database is called 'claims' table is called 'Claim_Status' and the column I need the WHERE to look is 'Practice_ID').

Any help appreciated - THANKS!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 problems here

This:

```
dim prac_id
prac_id = Request.Form("form1")
```

Needs to be:

```
dim prac_id
prac_id = Request.Form("Practice_ID")
```

form1 is the name of the form being submitted where you want Practice_ID which is the name of the dropdown being submitted

And this:

```
If request("prac_id")<>"" then
```

should be:

```
If prac_id <> "" then
```

request("prac_id") has no value so doesn't print anything to the page

You should also check to make sure prac_id is actually a number to prevent any sql injection attempts I would do:

```
If prac_id <> "" And IsNumeric(prac_id) then
```

**Part 2**

dim prac_id
prac_id = Request.Form("Practice_ID")

Change to:

dim prac_id, client_surname
prac_id = Request.Form("Practice_ID")
client_surname = Request.Form("clientsurname")

You then need to add this inot your SQL Statement

rs.Open "SELECT Date_Passed, Agent_ID, Client_First_Name, Client_Surname, Main_Number, Claims_Status FROM Claim_Status WHERE Practice_ID = '"&prac_id&"'", conn

Changes to:

rs.Open "SELECT Date_Passed, Agent_ID, Client_First_Name, Client_Surname, Main_Number, Claims_Status FROM Claim_Status WHERE Practice_ID = '"&prac_id&"' AND Client_Surname LIKE '%" & client_surname & "%'", conn

This will return any record where the search string is included anywhere in the surnam ie. a search for smith would return smith, smithson and jensmith

for an exact match change

Client_Surname LIKE '%" & client_surname & "%'"

to

Client_Surname = '" & client_surname & "'"

Or if you would like to return any surnames which start with the search string with ie. a search for smith would return smith and smithson

change to:

Client_Surname LIKE '" & client_surname & "%'"

Have a look at INNER JOIN to combine your 2 tables so the name can be returned in the same record set

Comment: This worked fine thanks!! I have two other things I want to try and implement in this: 1 - Looking up the surname, where would i start with trying to look up using surname, the surname would be input in to the second part of them form after the drop down menu, the column called 'Client_Surname' would be where to find the matching name. The second is displaying an agent name instead of an Agent ID in column 2 (the agent name is in a different table in my SQL database called PI_Agents (the columns are Agent_ID and Agent_Name. Thanks!

Comment: thanks again for this, however i'm getting this error message:  Expected end of statement

/default.asp, line 9

dim prac_id, client_surname prac_id = Request.Form("Practice_ID") client_surname = Request.Form("clientsurname")
It points to the  'P' in the second prac_ID

Comment: It's OK. I've cracked the surname thing now. Is there an easy way of displaying all records, as you can see I have an 'All' option for practices in the drop down but unsure how I can show all records when this option is selected?

Comment: A clean and simple way, given the above setup, is to simply format your SQL statement differently based on the value of prac_id. If 0 (= to the "All" option), format your SQL statement with no where clause or whatever actually reflects all records in your table. Otherwise, format it as you currently have it set up. So it's just a  simple if/then statement.